# how to force redirect to login page in javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication

I am building a website where I want users to have to log in to be able to view a certin page (kn this case it is called gallery.php) I implemented some code I found on this site, which redirects the user back to the login page when they click on the gallery link in the menu. However when I log in, and get redirected to the gallery again, the website does not acknowledge that I have logged in and redirects me back to the login page again. I am aware that questions like this have been asked before, but any help would be appreciated. My code is bellow

```
//from login.html 
<!--//
/*This Script allows people to enter by using a form that asks for a
UserID and Password*/
function pasuser(form) {
if (form.id.value=="Admin") { 
if (form.pass.value=="rycbar123") { 
var sessionTimeout = 1; //hours
var loginDuration = new Date();
loginDuration.setTime(loginDuration.getTime()+(sessionTimeout*60*60*1000));
document.cookie = "SistaDansenSession=Valid; "+loginDuration.toGMTString()+"; path=gallery.php";             
location="gallery.php" 
} else {
alert("Invalid Password")
}
} else {  alert("Invalid UserID")
}
}

//from gallery.php
<!--force login code-->
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.cookie.indexOf("SistaDansenSession=Valid") == -1) {
alert("You must be logged in to view this page")
location.href = "login.html";
}
else {
alert("login succesful")
}  </script>
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("SistaDansenSession=Valid") == -1)
```

to

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("SistaDansenSession") < 0)
```

When you set the cookie, you are setting the cookie attribute 'SistaDansenSession' equal to the value 'Valid'.  In your original code, you are attempting to retrieve a cookie attribute 'SistaDansenSession=Valid', whereas the attribute you want to retrieve is just 'SistaDansenSession'.  When the cookie is set, the attribute exists, so it will have an index that is >= 0. In that case, the redirect to the login does not occur - which I think is your desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. You are right, I do not want to be redirected to the login page a second time. I tried implementing your code, but the page still continues to try and redirect me.